# Should I insert an article in this sentence?

Tags: articles, definite-article

> A and B shared a high acoustic parameter, while C <del>shown</del> showed (the) low acoustic parameters.

Should I insert "the" in the place of bracket? To be honest, I am confused by the articles of English (especially definite-articles).

Comment: This sentence is confusing anyway. Why do you separate A and B from C with a "while", when they show the same (low) parameter value?

Comment: It's my leak to miswrite the "high" as "low" of the first phrase.

Comment: Not your "leak" (a leak is caused by a hole in a bucket, for example, or by a failed gasket). Rather, your "error".

Comment: It is extremely difficult to say with certainty which article is most appropriate when we have only one sentence for context. In the right context, *the* would be correct. So decisions about the use of articles rely on surrounding context perhaps more so than any other question over word usage. Which is why those single sentence tests where you fill in the blank with the "correct" article are pretty much useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "showed" you could say "was associated with" or "was characterized by".  You would not use "the".  You should probably not use "a" either with A and B.  But we'd need to know more, to be able to say for certain.

The phrase "to share a high...parameter" is not entirely clear. You need to clarify what "high...parameter" means.  Parameters are not high or low; rather the values of the parameter are high or low.

So "value" would be a better term here for *parameter*.

With respect to articles (a, the). Let's take this definition of **parameter**:

*any of a set of physical properties whose **values** determine the characteristics or behavior of something*  [my emphasis] 
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parameter

There is a *set* of properties, so we do not say "a" or "the". Such properties might be density, pressure, temperature.  Each member of the set has a *range* of possible values.

**A and B shared|had in common high pressure, while C was characterized by low pressure.**

or

**A and B both were characterized by high pressure, while C showed low pressure.**

You need to specify *which* parameter.

**A and B both were characterized by a high backscatter coefficient, while C showed a low backscatter coefficient.**

EXTRA CREDIT QUESTION:
Now, why did I use "*a* low backscatter coefficient" instead of "low backscatter coefficient"?

EXTRA EXTRA CREDIT:

If *multiple* tests were conducted, and A and B and C each had multiple associated test results, how would we state the backscatter coefficient result(s)?

Comment: Oh I see, "backscatter coefficient" is a definite values rather than a range of possibile values.

Comment: Yes, the distinction is between a range of possible values for the property and a definite or constant value.